# Installing SharePoint on standalone machine

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation

Trying to install Sharepoint  on Windows 2016 standalone server for learning purposes. Computer runes in default workgroup: WORKGROUP  During installation I have selected "Create new server farm" and on the next window I got Configuration Database Settings:
[image]

Since it is standaone machine I decided to connect to local database but install is not happy about username:

```
---------------------------
SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard
---------------------------
The specified user Administrator is a local account. Local accounts should only be used in stand alone mode.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

How to deal in this situation? I was trying to pass WORKGROUP\Administrator in username, but got error:

```
---------------------------
SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard
---------------------------
The username is invalid.  The account must be a valid domain account.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

How to solve database configuration in standalone machine?

UPD

I have installed domain controller on my machine and  have run SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard. At this time configuration failed since failure in DB connection:

```
---------------------------
SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard
---------------------------
Cannot connect to database master at SQL server at KPV. The database might not exist, or the current user does not have permission to connect to it.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Does it means that I must install MS SQL server also?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint does not support installation in a non-domain joined environment.

[Certain Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 installation scenarios are not supported](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2764086/certain-microsoft-sharepoint-server-2013-installation-scenarios-are-no)

Comment: I have updated my question body with additional info. Should I install MS SQL server for Sharepoint?